# How to listen for a change in app permission

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

Currently looking for a way to listen for if an app's lock screen permission has been revoked.

I know one can actively query for an app's access information with:

```
var accessStatus = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundExecutionManager.getAccessStatus();
```

But I am looking for a way to listen to any change (or at least revocation) to the lock screen or notification permission status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app can register that a background task is run when it is removed from the lock screen.  In addition, an app can similarly find out if it is *added* to the lock screen - a user can add an app to the lock screen without the app requesting itself to be added (e.g., when the app is not running via user settings).

The system triggers of interest are
[`lockScreenApplicationAdded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.Aspx) and [`lockScreenApplicationRemoved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.Aspx).

The [background task sample on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9/view/SourceCode) can be adapted to be trigger a background task when the user adds or removes the app from the lock screen.

Comment: Thank you so much; this sounds promising. I'll get back to you if this is the answer. I searched up and down MSDN, but not always easy to find the specific call you are looking for when all you know the end result you desire.